# Responding to a folder being dragged onto the Dock icon in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa

To respond to a file being dropped on the dock icon I would implement the openFile: method in the application delegate.  Is it the same for a folder? Also, where in the .plist do I declare that the application should be able to open folders?

Comment: Found a solution?